# How to tap on TableView Cell and navigate to another TableView in the next ViewController (local JSON file)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I have the following JSON file that is saved locally in my Xcode project.

```
{
  "mealPlan": [
    {
      "title": "Meal One",
      "instructions": [
        "This is step number 1 for Meal One.",
        "This is step number 2 for Meal One.",
        "This is step number 3 for Meal One.",
        "This is step number 4 for Meal One."
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Meal Two",
      "instructions": [
        "This is step number 1 for Meal Two.",
        "This is step number 2 for Meal Two.",
        "This is step number 3 for Meal Two.",
        "This is step number 4 for Meal Two."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below are my structs for `MealPlan` and `MealPlanService`:

```
struct MealPlan: Decodable {
    
    var title:String?
    var instructions:[String]?
    
}
```

```
struct MealPlanService: Decodable {
    
    var mealPlan:[MealPlan]?
    
}
```

In my first ViewController, I have successfully displayed a TableView with my mealPlan titles (e.g. "Meal One" and "Meal Two") through a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.

```
class MealPlanCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    var mealPlanToDisplay:MealPlan?
    
    func displayMealPlan(_ mealPlan:MealPlan) {
        
        // Keep a reference to the mealPlan
        mealPlanToDisplay = mealPlan
        
        // Set the titleLabel
        titleLabel.text = mealPlan.title
        
    }
```

And in ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var model = MealPlanModel()
    var mealPlan = [MealPlan]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set ViewController as the datasource and delegate of the tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        // Use MealPlanModel to get the mealPlans from the JSON File
        model.delegate = self
        model.getMealPlans()
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        // Detect the indexPath the user selected
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        
        guard indexPath != nil else {
            // The user hasn't selected anything
            return
        }
        
        // Get the mealPlan the user selected
        let mealPlanSelected = mealPlan[indexPath!.row]
        
        // Get a reference to the InstructionViewController
        let instructionVC = segue.destination as! InstructionViewController
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mealPlan.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        // Get the mealPlan that the tableView is asking about
        let mealPlanInTable = mealPlan[indexPath.row]
        
        // Customize the cell
        cell.displayMealPlan(mealPlanInTable)
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: MealPlanProtocol {
    
    func mealPlansRetrieved(_ mealPlans: [MealPlan]) {
        
        print("MealPlan retrieved from model (ViewController).")
        
        // Set the mealPlans property of the ViewController to the mealPlans passed back from the model
        self.mealPlan = mealPlans
        
        // Refresh the tableView
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

There are 2 things that I've spent a lot of time searching/trying but still can't figure out.

1. How to display items from my `instructions` array into a Table

I'm using the same model for displaying the `mealPlan` in the first ViewController and `instructions` in the second ViewController.

```
protocol MealPlanProtocol {
    
    func mealPlansRetrieved(_ mealPlans:[MealPlan])
    
}

class MealPlanModel {
    
    var delegate:MealPlanProtocol?
    
    func getMealPlans() {
        
        // Fetch mealPlans from MealPlansData.json
        getLocalJsonFile()
        
    }
    
    func getLocalJsonFile() {

        // Get bundle path to the MealPlansData.json
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MealPlansData", ofType: "json")

        // Double check that the path isn't nil
        guard path != nil else {
            print("Could not find MealPlansData.json.")
            return
        }

        // Create URL object from the path
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do {

            // Get the data from the URL
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            // Attempt to parse MealPlansData.json into objects
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let mealPlanService = try decoder.decode(MealPlanService.self, from: data)
            
            // Get the Meal Plans
            let mealPlans = mealPlanService.mealPlan!
            
            // Get the Instructions
            let instructions = [MealPlan().instructions]
            
            // Notify the delegate of the parsed mealPlanService objects
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans)
            }
            

        }

        catch {

            // Error: could not download the data at that URL
            print("Could not download the data at that URL.")
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm using a different custom subclass of the UITableViewCell for the second ViewController.

```
class InstructionCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var instructionLabel: UILabel!
    
    var mealPlanToDisplay:MealPlan?
    let mealPlan = MealPlan()
    
    func displayInstruction(_ currentMealPlan:MealPlan) {
        
        // Keep a reference to the mealPlan
        mealPlanToDisplay = currentMealPlan
        
        // Get the instructions data
        var instruction = mealPlan.instructions
        
        // Set the instructionLabel
        instructionLabel.text = currentMealPlan.instructions![]
        
    }
```

And this is my second ViewController where I want the `instructions` to display in the Table View.

```
class InstructionViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = MealPlanModel()
    var mealPlan = [MealPlan]()
    var instructions = [MealPlan().instructions]
    var currentMealPlanIndex = 0
    var currentInstructionIndex = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set InstructionViewController as the datasource and delegate of the tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        // Use the InstructionModel to get the instructions from the JSON file
        model.delegate = self
        model.getMealPlans()
    }
}

extension InstructionViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // Make sure the MealPlan array contains at least 1 instruction
        // TODO: - Get the instructions from the selected mealPlan
        let instructionsInMealPlan = instructions
        guard instructionsInMealPlan.count > 0 else {
            return 0
        }
        
        return instructionsInMealPlan.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InstructionCell", for: indexPath) as! InstructionCell
        
        // Get the instruction that the tableView is asking about
        // TODO: - Specify the mealPlan that was selected in ViewController
        let instructionInTable = mealPlan[indexPath.row].instructions![indexPath.row]
        
        // Customize the cell
        cell.displayInstruction(mealPlan[0])
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell

    }
```

In the `InstructionCell`, I'm not sure how to get the `instructions` data from my JSON file. I tried to get the `mealPlan` data the same as I did in `MealPlanCell`, but then to dive deeper I tried to call `mealPlan.instructions`. Seems like I'm not getting "an array of an array" properly (e.g. `instructions` arrays of the `mealPlan` array).

2. How to populate the Table View with the appropriate set of `instructions`. For example, I want tapping on mealPlan[0] in the first ViewController to give me mealPlan[0].instructions in the second ViewController. Right now I have a general segue from the TableView Cells in the first ViewController to navigate to the second ViewController. It seems like I should be using  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to get to a specific set of instructions, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to the question but the code in `numberOfRowsInSection` in `InstructionViewController` is pretty cumbersome. Just `return instructions.count` does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my 2 questions below.

1. How to display items from my instructions array into a Table.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InstructionCell", for: indexPath) as! InstructionCell
        
        // Get the instruction that the tableView is asking about
        let instructionLabel = cell.instructionLabel
        
        if instructionLabel != nil {
            
            let currentMealPlan = mealPlan[currentMealPlanIndex]
            
            if currentMealPlan.instructions != nil && indexPath.row < currentMealPlan.instructions!.count {
                // Set the instruction text for the instructionLabel
                instructionLabel!.text = currentMealPlan.instructions![indexPath.row]
            }
            
        }
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell

    }
```

`instructionLabel!.text = currentMealPlan.instructions![indexPath.row]` is what I was missing to set the InstructionViewController from my instructions array within my mealPlans array.

2. How to populate the Table View with the appropriate set of instructions.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        // Detect the indexPath the user selected
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        
        guard indexPath != nil else {
            // The user hasn't selected anything
            return
        }
        
        // Get the mealPlan the user selected
        let mealPlanSelected = mealPlan[indexPath!.row]
        
        // Get a reference to the InstructionViewController
        let instructionVC = segue.destination as! InstructionViewController
        
        // Get a reference to the currentMealPlanIndex
        instructionVC.currentMealPlanIndex = indexPath!.row
        
    }
```

I got a reference to the ViewController in my InstructionViewController. This link was very helpful: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do this.

In the first ViewController (the one with the meals table view), add the `didSelectRowAtMethod` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let selectedMeal = mealPlan[indexPath.row] //this the mealPlan you selected
    let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCIdentifier") as! InstructionViewController
    detailVC.meal = selectedMeal
    present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Your `detailViewcontroller` (the one where you display the instructions) should look really similar to the meals `ViewController`. You need a tableView to display each instruction in the instructions array in a cell.

Code for detail view controller:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController{

weak var meal: MealPlan?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func ViewDidLoad(){
    super.ViewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.datasource = self
 }

}

extension DetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return meal.instructions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as! InstructionCell
    cell.instruction = meal.instruction[indexPath.row]
    cell.displayInstruction()
    return cell
}
```

}

Almost there!!
One last thing. You just need to pass the single instruction to the instruction cell.
Edit the InstructionCell code like this

```
class InstructionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var instructionLabel: UILabel!

var instruction: String?

func displayInstruction() {
    
    
    // Set the instructionLabel
    instructionLabel.text = instruction
    
}
```

Comment: Hey Luca. Thank you so much for the thoughtful answer! It definitely helped guide me in the right direction. I did some research and tried a few things after reading your response and will post the answer shortly.